# Xamarin.Forms data binding to object's child array

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm creating several Editors in my codebehind and I'd like to bind their TextProperty to an object's string from an array. Object is declared inside ViewModel.

Code behind:

```
Editor text = new Editor();
text.SetBinding(Editor.TextProperty, "Here one string from string array in an object");
```

Object

```
public VObject {
  public string[] strings;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public VObject CurrentObject { 
   get { return _currentObject; } 
   set 
   {
      _currentObject = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an index to specify which array element to use

```
text.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, "strings[0]");
```

Comment: Thank You for replying! I'm wondering how can i get acces to CurrentObject from codebehind?

Comment: text.SetBinding (Editor.TextProperty, "CurrentObject.strings[0]"); will be fine?

Comment: if that's a property of the ViewModel, then yes

Comment: I'm getting an error: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.'

Comment: Everything works as You wrote, problem was in my code. Thank You very much for Your help!